# Need help with substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with substituting to differential equation:

> $$y\,y'_x=\left(ax+b\right)^{-2}\,y+1$$
>   The substitution $a\xi=-\left(ax+b\right)^{-1}$ leads to an equation of the form $y\,y'_\xi=y+\left(a\xi\right)^{-2}$.

I'm not sure where to even begin with this problem, so no attempts have been made.

Comment: Calculate $\frac{dx}{d\xi}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This substitution gives a change of independent variable (from $x$ to $\xi$).
So, this involves an application of the Chain Rule in the following manner:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{d\xi} \frac{d\xi}{dx} = (ax+b)^{-2} \frac{dy}{d\xi}$, since $\xi = -a^{-1} (ax+b)^{-1}$.

(In other words, $y'_x = (ax+b)^{-2} y'_{\xi} = (a \xi)^2 y'_{\xi} $.)

Now, $yy'_{x} = (ax+b)^{-2}y + 1$ transforms to 
$y \cdot (a \xi)^2 y'_{\xi} = (a \xi)^2 y + 1$.

Multiplying both sides by $(a \xi)^{-2}$ gives your transformed differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

The notation is a bit strange, but presumably what is meant is the differential equation

$$ y \dfrac{dy}{dx} = (ax+b)^{-2} y + 1 $$
i.e.
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = (ax+b)^{-2} + y^{-1}$$

If $a \xi = - (ax+b)^{-1}$, then $$\dfrac{d\xi}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{(ax+b)^2}$$
so by the Chain Rule

$$ \dfrac{dy}{d\xi} = \dfrac{dy/dx}{d\xi/dx} = \ldots$$